# Define Projection/setting coordinate system is not saved in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, arcmap

I've downloaded a GMT grid from http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/pibhmc/cms/data-by-location/northwest-hawaiian-islands/submerged-banks/gardner-pinnacles/gardner-pinnacles-bathymetry/ which doesn't include a spatial reference, but according to the text file should be in UTM Zone 3. I am unable to add the spatial reference. What I tried:
0

1. in ArcMap (10.8.1): Data Management Tools>Projections and Transformations>Define Projection
2. in ArcCatalog: choosing a spatial reference in the properties of the raster.

In both cases, the spatial reference is not applied to the raster. I'm not sure why this is happening or how else to fix this.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the necessary permissions on the filesystem? Since this is certainly a capability of the software, you'll need to provide more details. For trouble-shooting exercises, an interactive session with Tech Support might be beneficial.

Comment: Probably because it's a NetCDF. Convert it to a GeoTIFF or FGDB Raster and set SRS.

Comment: @user2856 I don't often work with rasters; how do I do that? Within ArcMap?

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/output-coordinate-system.htm